# The Function of "parent, true" or "null, true"

Tags: android, listview

I'm learning how to create ListView in Android Studio. I've looked at a lot of ListView examples and there is a part in the examples which I don't understand why is used. The following lines of code include the part I mean:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, parent, false//the function of "parent, false"?);

View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null, true//the function of "null, true"?);
```

What are "parent, true" and "null, true" used for?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The online documentation for LayoutInflater explains this pretty well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter (`parent` or `null`) in your samples indicates the eventual parent of the root view being inflated from the layout file. Mostly, this is to help `RelativeLayout` interpret its layout rules properly.

The third parameter (`true` or `false`) indicates whether the inflated view should be added as a child of the designated parent immediately (`true`) or not (`false`).

Your second example should never be used, as there is no parent to add the inflated view to, and so `true` makes no sense here.

If you are using `inflate()`, the first form is the one you will use almost all of the time. If you know the parent, provide it. Usually, you will pass `false` for the third parameter, as something else (`ListView`, `RecyclerView`, `FragmentManager`, etc.) will determine when the inflated child is attached to its parent.

Comment: thank you very much for your easy-to-understand explanation!